# Core data predicate with group and MAX()

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an object in core data that has 2 fields: Name and Date.  Each time a person checks in it saves their name and the time they did it.

Is there a way to get a list of all unique people with their last check in time using a predicate in core data?

Note: i do know that 2 tables would make it easier.

the sql for this would be

```
select 
    clientName
    , MAX(ModifiedDate) 
from
    Client
group by 
    clientName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No not easily since Core Data is an object graph first.  You could do it by grabbing a distinct set of the names and then querying for the max for each via a sort.

The best answer is to break it into two tables otherwise it is going to be computationally expensive each time you try and resolve this.

### OR/M Layer

Don't think of it as an OR/M layer.  Core Data is an object graph; full stop.

The fact that it happens to persist to a database structure as one of its persistence options is secondary.

The issue in your question is that you are trying to use an Object Graph as a database.  In that situation I get to use a phase that is very frequently attributed to me:

"You're doing it wrong." :)

Comment: That is what I thought.  Nothing like another OR/M layer to make things easier :).

Comment: I'd go even farther and say that if you think of Core Data as using tables, you're going to do it wrong. Entities look a lot like tables but thinking of them that way leads to inappropriate database-style thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning from iOS 5.0 / OS X 10.7 `NSFetchRequest` class includes the `setPropertiesToGroupBy:` instance method, which allow to create aggregated requests on persistent storage level.

You would have to set `NSDictionaryResultType` as the result type, thus telling `NSFetchRequest` object to return `NSDictionary` objects with aggregated data instead of managed objects.

Example code for max() requests:

```
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSExpression *dateKeyExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *maxDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dateKeyExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *maxDateED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[maxDateED setExpression:maxDateExpression];
[maxDateED setName:@"maxDate"];
[maxDateED setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

NSAttributeDescription *clientName = [[self entityDescription].attributesByName objectForKey:@"clientName"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:clientName, maxDateED, nil]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:clientName]];
```