# Fetch unique core data entities with @max predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data structure like follows:

```
+-------+-----+---------+
| uid   | id  | category
+-------+-----+---------+
| 12345 |  1  | 1
| 23456 |  1  | 1
| 34567 |  2  | 1
| 45678 |  2  | 2
| 56789 |  2  | 2
+-------+-----+---------+
```

Is it possible to query the data such that I am returned NSManagedObjects (not dictionaries) with unique id/category combinations?  Using the sample table above, I'd like to have an array that contains objects with the following uids: 23456 (max uid for id-1 category-1), 34567 (max uid for id-2 category-1), 56789 (max uid for id-2 category-2)

With raw SQL I can do this with the following:

```
SELECT MAX(uid), id, category FROM TABLE GROUP BY id, category
```

Is it possible to translate the above SQL into an NSFetchRequest?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197141/core-data-predicate-with-group-and-max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of other answers (such as the one pointed to by Martin R), I broke this up into two parts.  First, use a fetch request with NSDictionaryResultType to get all the max uids:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSExpression *expr = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"uid"];
NSExpression *maxExpr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:@[expr]];
NSExpressionDescription *exprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[exprDesc setExpression:maxExpr];
[exprDesc setName:@"uid"];

NSPropertyDescription *id = [[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"id"];
NSPropertyDescription *cat = [[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"category"];

[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:id, cat, nil]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:exprDesc, nil]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSArray *maxUids = [result valueForKeyPath:@"uid"];
```

Second, use the maxUids array to fetch the corresponding NSManagedObjects using the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uid IN %@)", maxUids];
```

The use of two fetch requests is less than ideal, but provides an alternative to using a SUBQUERY and/or changing the underlying data model.