# fetch all other values in row for maximum value of group by using core data in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I worked based on this link

[Core data predicate with group and MAX()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197141/core-data-predicate-with-group-and-max)

Only two column values are fetched. 
MaxDate and clientName.
I need all other values like client_id, number which is present in same row of MaxDate.

I have used same code. please suggest me to get other attributes of same row.

Equivalent for the sqlite query

"SELECT *, MAX(DATE)” \
                        "FROM IM_INFO GROUP BY CLIENTNAME;”

I have used this code.

```
NSExpression *dateKeyExpression = [NSExpression     expressionForKeyPath:@"date"];
NSExpression *maxDateExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dateKeyExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *maxDateED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[maxDateED setExpression:maxDateExpression];
[maxDateED setName:@"maxDate"];
[maxDateED setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];

NSAttributeDescription *clientName = [[self entityDescription].attributesByName objectForKey:@"clientName"];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:clientName, maxDateED, nil]];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:clientName]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Comment: did you try adding them to the list of names you want?

Comment: ya added. but its throwing error

Comment: following error     " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions"

Comment: i guess you'll need to do a fetch request then

Comment: in the above code, request is object of fetch request.

Comment: a *second* fetch request to get the complete details

Comment: ya, its working thank you